# get clean URL from UI routing and achieve share functionality

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, share, clean-urls, angularjs-ng-route

i need a clean URL for my angular JS project. And i am using ui-Routing(nested routing).

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) { 

//State routing 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider.state('home', {      
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',

})
.state('home.HomeInner', {      
    url:'/HomeInner',
    templateUrl: 'HomeInner/HomeInner.html',
})

    .state('home.news_detail', {        
    url:'/news_detail/name=:name',
    params: {
        'spareParam' : 'whateverString'
    },
    templateUrl: 'news_detail/news_detail.html',
})
```

});

i have URL like **http://example.com/#!/home/news_detail/name=112**

i needed URL Like-**http://example.com/**

if it is possible to make make my URL like i need how can i perform share functionality

Comment: have you tried `$location.$$absUrl`

Comment: @Edison  Thanks for the quick response.We are trying to make a clean URL.in this http://example.com/#!/home/news_detail/name=112 URL my share functionality working fine.